Copy location constraint with vertex group not working anymore on 4.2 version
I'm trying to make a render of a sailing boat that floats on a ocean, so as many tutorial suggested, I've created a plane, I've shrinkwrapped it on my ocean, I've created a vertex group and use it to copy its location to my ship.
I've done this in version 4.0 and for reasons I've upgraded the project to 4.2, but now the boat seems to just stay still. I've tried to duplicate the same project and convert one of them, to be sure that there are no changes involved, but this is it.
Is this the intended behaviour of the constraint that have been fixed? Is it a missing feature?
Is there another way or a better way to do it? I'm just curious to know.
